# facebook app publish_actions can not resubmitted

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish-actions

I have an app and have got publish_actions this permission few months ago
now I need a new permission "user_photos"
so I build a simple web game that can upload photo to user album and get user album photo url showing on the page so this game include two permissions "user_photos" and "publish_actions".

Now I start a new submission but unapproved by facebook review team
they say

```
"To allow your app to publish content onto a timeline, please resubmit with the publish_actions permission."
```

but I have got publish_actions few months ago and this "publish_actions"
dose not show in the permission items list because this list does not show
those permissions which you have got before so there is no 
"publish_actions" I can click and choose

So I do not know how to "resubmit" publish_actions which does not show in the item list..

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I think you need to upgrade to Facebook's new SDK that is 4.0 
The FBSDKLoginKit and FBSDKShareKit are the new implementations for this.

Comment: This seems like an issue on our side, apologies for that. The best way to solve this is to go over to the Facebook Developer Community group [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/) and post all your info, including your application ID. The review team are active there and will get back to you on this. You do not need to update your SDK.